# Using Infinity in GeoServer SLD colormapentry?

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld

I am trying to write an SLD with the last interval ending at infinity, (i.e. have the last interval include arbitrarily large numbers. Currently, I am using a large value like this:

```
      <RasterSymbolizer>
        <ColorMap type="intervals">
            ...
            <ColorMapEntry color="#08306b" quantity="1000000" />
```

But there are always cases when this value `1000000` is exceeded.

How can I make this stopping value infinite?

Note:

I looked at the example [here](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/main/src/test/java/org/geoserver/data/test/rainfall_classes.sld), and tried

```
<ColorMapEntry color="#08306b" quantity="Infinity" />
```

but I get an error saying that:

```
line 23: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'Infinity' is not a valid value for 'double'.
line 23: cvc-attribute.3: The value 'Infinity' of attribute 'quantity' on element 'ColorMapEntry' is not valid with respect to its type, 'double'.
```

when validating the SLD with GeoServer 2.5

Comment: try not to valid the style. Submit it directly and check if that works.

validation should not be required for a style to work in some corner cases where geoserver does extend SLD.